# Using id to get li elements from two ul lists

Tags: javascript

First up, I'm a total noob with Javascript, no doubt! This Javascript is for a search list and filtering items out of that list. It works pretty well, but only for one of the `ul` lists (the first one) in the code.

So the question is, how do I get it to work for both `ul` lists. I've tried renaming `id`s for the second list and posting the script again with changed `id`s and so on, but nothing really seems to work.
Thank you in advance, I am really stuck and don't know what to try next.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Name..">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a class="volcanion-unb">Volcanion (UNB)</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-vmax">Centiskorch Vmax</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-v">Centiskorch V</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Name..">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a class="volcanion-unb2">Volcanion (UNB)</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-vmax2">Centiskorch Vmax</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-v2">Centiskorch V</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using same ids for both lists you'll never get the second list.

This lines from script will select the first input and first ul

  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

Have you tried changing the ids and passing as a parameter to myFunction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is only working for the first list has to do with this line:

```
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
```

The `getElementById` method will only return one element, so it is completely ignoring the second element with the same `id`. ([More information on `getElementById` here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)) It is generally a "best practice" to use an `id` only once per html page.

In order to get around this, you could give the other `ul` a different `id` (let's say `<ul id="myUL2">`).  However, I think it would be much more efficient to get all the `li`s at once, as you originally intended.  You should be able to simply to skip assigning `ul` altogether and do this:

```
li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

This will grab the `li` elements from the whole `document`, for you to then manipulate as desired.  ([More information on `getElementsByTagName` here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp))

Here is that solution inserted into your original code:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Name..">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a class="volcanion-unb">Volcanion (UNB)</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-vmax">Centiskorch Vmax</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-v">Centiskorch V</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Name..">
<ul id="myUL2">
  <li><a class="volcanion-unb2">Volcanion (UNB)</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-vmax2">Centiskorch Vmax</a></li>
  <li><a class="centiskorch-v2">Centiskorch V</a></li>
</ul>
     
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('myInput');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```